# Should object free objects which it contains?

Tags: delphi, class

Recently I have a dillema.

Consider such example:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FDataStream: TMemoryStream;
    procedure SetDataStream(const Value: TMemoryStream);
  public
    property DataStream: TMemoryStream read FDataStream write SetDataStream;
    constructor Create(ADataStream: TMemoryStream);
    destructor Destroy;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyObject }

constructor TMyObject.Create(ADataStream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  FDataStream := ADataStream;
end;

destructor TMyObject.Destroy;
begin
  //Should MyObject free FDataStream?
end;

procedure TMyObject.SetDataStream(const Value: TMemoryStream);
begin
  FDataStream := Value;
end;

end.
```

As you see, the TMyObject can have an instance of TMemoryStream. Now, I am wondering what TMyobject should do when it is freed? Should it also free FDataStram or should it left as it is?

Is there any guidline for such scenerio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the example you give it seems to me that your TMyObject receives an instance from somewhere else. If it isn't in the TMyObject constructor's to take over ownership of the stream it receives, it should certainly not free it when it is destroyed.

To preserve your sanity, stick to this rule: **the class/code that instantiates an object should destroy it**.

And as your constructor does not create the data stream instance, the destructor should not free it.

Comment: While in general, I agree with the line in bold, you and I know that there are situations where this is not the case (e.g. a container with OwnsObjects semantics). In this case, I would not free the stream either.

Comment: @Rudy: of course. I would put that under the "transfer ownership" heading. Either as part of the "contract" of what you pass into a constructor or of what you pass to an Add method of a container/collection. Transfer of ownership is one of those situations where you deliberately and in full awareness of the consequences, deviate from an otherwise "hard and fast" rule.

Answer (score 3):

TMyObject didn't create the TMemoryStream itself. The stream was given as a reference to TMyObject via the constructor, so TMyObject should not free it. Freeing the memorystream is the responsibility of whoever created it.

Comment: What if it was created with: `TMyObject.Create(TMemoryStream.Create);`, as I'd probably do?

Comment: @Rudy, wouldn't you then let the TMyObject own and create it?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are supposed to free it or not depends on semantics. If you are the *sole user* of the stream and the (previous) owner supposes you own it, then you should free it when you are finished.

This is indicated by user code that does something like:

```
x := TMyCode.Create(TMemoryStream.Create));
```

When you are the owner, the user only has to create the stream (memory, file, etc.) and hand to to you.

If you, however, were only given the memorystream owned by other code in order to read a part and then the owner of the stream passes it to another class/routine, then it is not yours and you should keep it alive.

This all depends on clear documentation indicating who will free what. It is not as clear as the previous posters make it look like. You (and the users of your class) can only decide what is best.

**You could of course add another Boolean property / parameter indicating if your class owns the object or not**. But only do that if it is unclear if the class is supposed to do that.

Comment: +1 The problem is how to detect if the stream was created in the way you have shown. Of course I could introduce a property like OwnsStream but this is getting messy when I have to pass more objects via constructor. The worst part is that if the class is private to its user for example user have only the DCU, he might create the memory stream and think that this is MyObject responsibility to free it...

Answer (score 1):

The object that owns the object should free it. Typically the object that creates it is the owner. That's the case in 99% or more of situations. Sometimes ownership is transferred to another object and when that happens it is the responsibility of the new owner to free the object.

Although I would point out that in your example, it doesn't matter what you put in Destroy since it will never be called - you forgot to mark it with the override directive.